# Странная форма прилагательного "дорогой"

Tags: падежи, выражения, idioms, родительный-падеж

> Но как-то разбрасываться таким знакомством нам не приходилось. Живой человек, к нам расположенный, и не мутант – это **дорогого** стоит в чужом городе.

Почему здесь используется родительный падеж? Я не вижу ничего, к чему он мог бы относиться.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Стоить** может управлять винительным падежом, «стоит **одну копейку**», но может управлять и родительным, когда речь идёт не о денежной стоимости, а о ценности, важности, т. е. в переносном значении: «Это стоило ему **многих усилий**». В выражении `дорогого стоит` «дорогое» значит «что-то дорогое», и может, в принципе, относиться к чему угодно, в зависимости от контекста, но вообще-то это цельная фразеологическая единица, которая значит «**имеет большую ценность**»:

> Но материнское сердце дорогого стоит.
>
> Красивая улыбка дорогого стоит.
>
> Мало слово, но дорогого стоит! (пословица)

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае употреблён распространённый, но вызывающий некоторые споры словесный штамп ("дорогого стоит"), который не нарушает падежных правил (родительный падеж уместен), но которому говорящие не придают буквального смысла. Его используют как идиому, обозначающую, что упомянутое перед этим событие (чей-то благородный поступок, похвала со стороны известного человека, чья-то оговорка с саморазоблачением и т.п.) о многом говорит или имеет особое значение. Буквальный же смысл предложения состоит в сопоставлении названного (здесь - того, что нашёлся благожелательно настроенный человек) с тем, что за это можно было бы без сожаления отдать в тех условиях (здесь - "нечто дорогое") - настолько наличие такого человека полезно.

Пример аналогичного использования родительного падежа в простейшей ситуации:

```
"купленный предмет (не) стоит заплаченных за него денег".
```

Пример классической поговорки с родительным падежом:

```
"Игра не стоит свеч"
```

(буквальный смысл: на свечи потратиться придётся, а выигрыш в карты этого не окупит; переносный смысл - "за это дело браться невыгодно").

Answer (score 0):

Русско-английский перевод `дорогого стоит`.
`Дорого стоит` употребляется в том числе в ироническом и даже саркастическом контексте it's worth a lot/a great deal; it's worth its weight in gold ( более вычурно ) Подарок Лужкова дорогого стоит («Новые Известия»). - Luzhkov's gift comes at a price.

Русско-Английский словарь общей тематики.       Russian-English dictionary of general subjects. 2012